# is null entity framework 5

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have this sentence in sql server:

```
SELECT * FROM Documentos WHERE ( @param IS NULL OR strNOMPRO = @param )
```

and I do this with entity

```
DocumentsList = db.DOCUMENTOS
                .Where(d => d.strNOMPRO == nombre && d.strNOMPRO == null)
                .OrderByDescending(d => d.datFECCER).ToList();
```

if param is null this return all the registers in sql but in linq return 0 registers

How i can do this well?

Comment: It looks like you accidentally used `&&` instead of `||` in your `.Where()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an equivalent of your SQL WHERE statement:

```
DocumentsList = db.DOCUMENTOS
                .Where(d => nomber == null || d.strNOMPRO == nombre)
                .OrderByDescending(d => d.datFECCER)
                .ToList();
```

It checks parameter for `null` OR ([|| Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx)) it checks that strNOMPRO property should be equal to parameter.

BTW thus your parameter cannot change in the middle of query, it's more efficient to add filtering condition dynamically:

```
var query = db.DOCUMENTOS;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nombre))
    query = query.Where(d => d.strNOMPRO == nombre);

DocumentsList = query.OrderByDescending(d => d.datFECCER).ToList();
```

Further readings: [&& Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) and [|| Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx)